# Failed to install xfce4 on Debian jessie

Tags: debian, xfce4

I followed instruction on the https://wiki.debian.org/Xfce‎ but got the error saying that:

```
dpkg: warning: 'ldconfig' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: warning: 'start-stop-daemon' not found in PATH or not executable
dpkg: error: 2 expected programs not found in PATH or not executable
Note: root's PATH should usually contain /usr/local/sbin, /usr/sbin and /sbin
```

apt-cache search ldconfig shows that it's included in libc-bin but I couldn't find start-stop-daemon. Also, I actual have never came across a system without ldconfig before. However does it ever work anyway?

Below is the PATH for root:

```
$ sudo env | grep PATH
PATH=/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/qt4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/games:
```

Comment: Run `sudo env | grep PATH` and add the result to your question.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Found the problem. Silly me!

Answer (score 0):

Xfce is a lightweight desktop environment for UNIX-like operating systems. It aims to be fast and low on system resources, while still being visually appealing and user friendly.

To install Xfce on debian 7 wheezy

```
# apt-get install xorg xfce4 xfce4-goodies thunar-archive-plugin synaptic gdebi wicd
```

To install extra XFCE packages

```
# apt-get install xdg-utils xfce4-power-manager xfce4-goodies htop bzip2 zip unzip unrar-free
```

There are more gui to choose from http://namhuy.net/1085/install-gui-on-debian-7-wheezy.html

Answer (score 0):

Another solution was for me to extract the start-stop-daemon file located in the dpkg installation .deb archive (in the /sbin folder), and put it into the /usr/sbin folder (it was missing from it in the first place, somehow).